# How to tell if AsyncTaskLoader is running

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I am starting a `AsyncTaskLoader` using this:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

I thought I could use this to tell if it's running:

```
Boolean isRunning = (getLoaderManager().getLoader(0) != null && getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).isStarted());
```

but `isRunning` always returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks' onLoadFinished method, I usually

```
getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(loader.getId());
```

then

```
Boolean isRunning = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0) != null
```